# Flex box items in chrome are not taking full width of parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In large screens, the image items are not taking the full width of parent, is problematic in chrome only, tried in firefox and safari, they were good! 
Tried some answers given on the look-alike questions in SO, but no luck!

Here is the codepen

```css
.THIS .masonry {
 height: auto !important;
}

.THIS .masonry::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
 
.THIS #columns {
 column-width: 250px;
 column-gap: 15px;
   width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:19px;
}

.THIS div#columns figure {
 background: #fefefe;
 border: 2px solid #eee;
 /*box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);*/
 margin: 0 2px 15px;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}

.THIS div#columns figure img {
 width: 100%; height: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.THIS div#columns figure figcaption {
    font-size: .8rem;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.THIS div#columns small { 
  font-size: 1rem;
  float: right; 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #aaa;
} 

.THIS div#columns small a { 
  color: #666; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  transition: .4s color;
}

.detail-figcaption + figcaption {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="THIS a">
<div class="masonry" id="columns" data-aura-rendered-by="81:0">
    <figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="1:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/s--UxAphIx0--/v1535010155/9413cd2cf45f7830a39fdd24025d6d21.png" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="2:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="3:377;a">, Painting, 438 X 318<br data-aura-rendered-by="10:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="31:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1531486409/IUII3rYZ9o.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="32:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="33:377;a">Paint TheArtist, Print/Drawing, 866 X 1200, Tel, Aviv, Israel<br data-aura-rendered-by="40:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="80:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1533722730/water_splash_background-t2.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="81:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="82:377;a">, 510 X 330<br data-aura-rendered-by="89:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="129:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1533713297/photo-1526599235054-9bd6a36c7885.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="130:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="131:377;a">, 1000 X 667<br data-aura-rendered-by="138:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="159:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1532070883/r9enqpbefz4mgrsccra5.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="160:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="161:377;a">, 594 X 917<br data-aura-rendered-by="168:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="189:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1532069623/nlll6ot75vuz9o0c1pfb.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="190:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="191:377;a">, 72 X 100<br data-aura-rendered-by="198:377;a"></figcaption>
    <!--render facet: 218:377;a-->
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="219:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1532010350/o9aeanqvhnprwmswmtfp.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="220:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="221:377;a">, 866 X 1200<br data-aura-rendered-by="228:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="249:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1532007196/y4ff0tjjeero2dpx0dwn.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="250:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="251:377;a">, 866 X 1200<br data-aura-rendered-by="258:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="item" data-aura-rendered-by="279:377;a">
    <img class="attachment-home-thumbnail size-home-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/tempuser3/image/upload/w_262,q_auto:low/v1532007107/i2vyk6dnafswojormblp.jpg" width="262" data-aura-rendered-by="280:377;a">
    <figcaption class="detail-figcaption" data-aura-rendered-by="281:377;a">, 866 X 1200<br data-aura-rendered-by="288:377;a"></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
</span>
```

the design is based on this code
https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw

Any workaround?

Comment: Did you forget `display: (inline-)flex;` in your code, I can't see it?

Comment: @FelipeAls yeah it was there previously, but removed later, now I added that again to try and made 2 changes for figure display:block and added -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; now it is working fine in chrome but in firefox the images are showing vertically!

now the working code difference between chrome and firefox is, the flex divs and inline-block thing. firefox works without flex divs!